# External HDD stops mounting just one drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

hope you are well.I usually use external HDD and it worked very well all the time, but today suddenly it stops and i disconnected it. After that when i connect it again my F drive is not mounting. I check it on windows and work perfectly. An unknown error occurred when mounting it. I'm using hp Elitebook 840 g5.
Please give me solution.

Comment: Was the disk in question last used on a Windows system with the "Fast boot" setting enabled?
  
The Windows "Fast Boot" setting leaves the disk partition in an undocumented, proprietary state that Linux isn't permitted to recognize. Boot back into Windows and disable "Fast Boot". Be prepared to have to re-disable "Fast Boot"  - Windows updates have been known to turn it back on. See https://www.windowscentral.com/how-disable-windows-10-fast-startup